# How to create a method which returns objects read from txt.file?

Tags: java, file, filereader

This is my attempt to read the file. If anyone has any comments about how to perform this in a better way, I am all ears.

```
public class Program {
    public void readFromFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
        File equipment = new File("equipment.txt");
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(equipment);
        while (reader.hasNextLine()){

        }
    }
}
```

This is my first Equipment class. The equipment from the txt file have some common properties. I only use this as an abstract class since that's what I think I have to do according to my task (test-Exam). If I am wrong, please let me know :)

```
public abstract class Equipment {
    private Integer id;
    private String locker;
    private Integer year;

    public Equipment(Integer id, String locker, Integer year) {
        this.id = id;
        this.locker = locker;
        this.year = year;
    }
```

Child equipment class drill. The drill only occurs three times within the txt file and I struggle to figure out how to read the content from the txt file when the drill and saw have some different properties.

```
public class Drill extends Equipment{
    private String equipmentName;
    private Boolean batteryPowered;
    private Boolean needsNewBit;

    public Drill(String equipmentName, Integer id, String locker, Integer year,  Boolean batteryPowered, Boolean needsNewBit) {
        super(id, locker, year);
        this.equipmentName = equipmentName;
        this.batteryPowered = batteryPowered;
        this.needsNewBit = needsNewBit;
    }
```

Child equipment class saw

```
public class Saw extends Equipment{
    private String equipmentName;
    private String sawType;
    private Boolean needsGrinding;

    public Saw(String equipmentName, Integer id, String locker, Integer year, String sawType, Boolean needsGrinding) {
        super(id, locker, year);
        this.equipmentName = equipmentName;
        this.sawType = sawType;
        this.needsGrinding = needsGrinding;
    }
```

Equipment.txt file format. I have separated the objects so it's easier to read. The txt file is originally without spaces in between the objects.

```
Saw
12
Locker 1
2012
Hand
true

Saw
15
Locker 2
2012
Hack
true

Saw
14
Locker 2
2014
Japanese
true

Saw
1
Locker 3
2014
Coping
false

Saw
2
Locker 3
2014
Coping
true

Saw
12
Locker 1
2016
Japanese
false

Saw
3
Locker 1
2016
Hack
true

Saw
5
Locker 4
2016
Hand
true

Saw
6
Locker 4
2019
Hand
true

Drill
16
Locker 5
2019
false
true

Drill
17
Locker 5
2019
false
true

Drill
18
Locker 5
2001
true
false

Saw
20
Locker 6
2001
Hack
false

Saw
21
Locker 6
2001
Hack
true

Saw
31
Locker 7
2021
Japanese
false

Saw
32
Locker 7
2021
Japanese
false

Saw
33
Locker 7
2021
Japanese
true

Saw
34
Locker 7
2018
Coping
false
```

Comment: As I understand it, every six lines in file `Equipment.txt` defines a piece of equipment. Are you asking how to create an instance of a relevant subclass of `Equipment` after reading the lines in the file that define it? By the way, I would argue that `equipmentName` should be in class `Equipment` rather than repeated in both class `Drill` and class `Saw`.

Comment: I'm not fully understanding how to define the question to be honest. As in my task description, it says :"Create a class that is responsible for being able to read equipment information from a file. When reading from file it should create objects that represent the saws and drills. The class must include a public method
which can return the objects read from file. You have to find out for yourself which classes you have to make in order to be able to
represent the saws and drills. It is expected that you use inheritance."I would assume the inheritance is by creating subclasses from equipment

Answer (score 2):

First the code.
(Explanations after.)

```java
public abstract class Equipment {
    private Integer id;
    private String locker;
    private Integer year;
    private String equipmentName;

    public Equipment(Integer id, String locker, Integer year, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.locker = locker;
        this.year = year;
        equipmentName = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s %s %s %s", equipmentName, id, locker, year);
    }
}
```

---

```java
public class Drill extends Equipment {
    private Boolean batteryPowered;
    private Boolean needsNewBit;

    public Drill(String equipmentName, Integer id, String locker, Integer year,  Boolean batteryPowered, Boolean needsNewBit) {
        super(id, locker, year, equipmentName);
        this.batteryPowered = batteryPowered;
        this.needsNewBit = needsNewBit;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s %s %s", super.toString(), batteryPowered, needsNewBit);
    }
}
```

---

```java
public class Saw extends Equipment {
    private String sawType;
    private Boolean needsGrinding;

    public Saw(String equipmentName, Integer id, String locker, Integer year, String sawType, Boolean needsGrinding) {
        super(id, locker, year, equipmentName);
        this.sawType = sawType;
        this.needsGrinding = needsGrinding;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s %s %s", super.toString(), sawType, needsGrinding);
    }
}
```

---

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program {
    private static final String  DRILL = "Drill";
    private static final String  SAW = "Saw";

    public List<Equipment> readFromFile() throws IOException {
        File equipment = new File("equipment.txt");
        List<Equipment> equipmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> fields = new ArrayList<>();
        String line;
        String type = null;
        Equipment equip = null;
        try (Scanner reader = new Scanner(equipment)) {
            while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
                line = reader.nextLine();
                if (isTypeLine(line)) {
                    if (type != null) {
                        switch (type) {
                            case DRILL:
                                equip = createDrill(fields);
                                break;
                            case SAW:
                                equip = createSaw(fields);
                                break;
                            default:
                                equip = null;
                        }
                        if (equip != null) {
                            equipmentList.add(equip);
                        }
                    }
                    fields.clear();
                    type = line;
                }
                else {
                    fields.add(line);
                }
            }
            if (type != null) {
                switch (type) {
                    case DRILL:
                        equip = createDrill(fields);
                        break;
                    case SAW:
                        equip = createSaw(fields);
                        break;
                    default:
                        equip = null;
                }
                if (equip != null) {
                    equipmentList.add(equip);
                }
            }
            return equipmentList;
        }
    }

    private Drill createDrill(List<String> fields) {
        Integer id = Integer.valueOf(fields.get(0));
        String locker = fields.get(1);
        Integer year = Integer.valueOf(fields.get(2));
        Boolean batteryPowered = Boolean.valueOf(fields.get(3));
        Boolean needsNewBit = Boolean.valueOf(fields.get(4));
        Drill drill = new Drill(DRILL, id, locker, year, batteryPowered, needsNewBit);
        return drill;
    }

    private Saw createSaw(List<String> fields) {
        Integer id = Integer.valueOf(fields.get(0));
        String locker = fields.get(1);
        Integer year = Integer.valueOf(fields.get(2));
        String sawType = fields.get(3);
        Boolean needsGrinding = Boolean.valueOf(fields.get(4));
        Saw saw = new Saw(SAW, id, locker, year, sawType, needsGrinding);
        return saw;
    }

    private boolean isTypeLine(String line) {
        return DRILL.equals(line)  ||  SAW.equals(line);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Program prog = new Program();
        try {
            List<Equipment> list = prog.readFromFile();
            list.forEach(System.out::println);
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            xIo.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

- I moved member `equipmentName` from the subclasses, i.e. `Drill` and `Saw`, to the superclass `Equipment` since one of the purposes of a base class is to contain members that are common to all subclasses. Hence better to have one `equipmentName` member in the superclass rather than have a separate member in each of the subclasses.
- I added method `toString` to each of the classes `Equipment`, `Drill` and `Saw` only for debugging purposes.
- In the text file, a group of lines, where the first line is either *Drill* or *Saw* defines a piece of equipment. Hence in the code (of method `readFromFile`, in class `Program`), whenever a line contains *Drill* or *Saw*, I save that in local variable `type`. I also know that we are starting a new definition. That means that either it is the first definition or that I have read all the lines that define the equipment. In the case of the latter, i.e. I have just read all the lines defining the equipment, I create an instance according to the value of `type`. I initialize `type` to null. This lets me know whether I am reading the first definition in the file.
- After creating the appropriate instance, i.e. `Drill` or `Saw`, I add it to the [list](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html).
- I use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) in method `readFromFile` to ensure that the file, *equipment.txt*, is closed.
- Also in method `readFromFile`, when the `while` loop terminates, there may be values in `fields` which I have not yet converted to an instance of either `Drill` or `Saw`. Hence the `if` statement that comes after the `while` loop.
- The following line (from method `main` in class `Program`) is known as a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html). It just saves me some typing and it is only to display the value returned by method `readFromFile` to check that I got the expected result.

```java
list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

The contents of file `equipment.txt`

```
Saw
12
Locker 1
2012
Hand
true
Saw
15
Locker 2
2012
Hack
true
Saw
14
Locker 2
2014
Japanese
true
Saw
1
Locker 3
2014
Coping
false
Saw
2
Locker 3
2014
Coping
true
Saw
12
Locker 1
2016
Japanese
false
Saw
3
Locker 1
2016
Hack
true
Saw
5
Locker 4
2016
Hand
true
Saw
6
Locker 4
2019
Hand
true
Drill
16
Locker 5
2019
false
true
Drill
17
Locker 5
2019
false
true
Drill
18
Locker 5
2001
true
false
Saw
20
Locker 6
2001
Hack
false
Saw
21
Locker 6
2001
Hack
true
Saw
31
Locker 7
2021
Japanese
false
Saw
32
Locker 7
2021
Japanese
false
Saw
33
Locker 7
2021
Japanese
true
Saw
34
Locker 7
2018
Coping
false
```

Output from running `Program`

```
Saw 12 Locker 1 2012 Hand true
Saw 15 Locker 2 2012 Hack true
Saw 14 Locker 2 2014 Japanese true
Saw 1 Locker 3 2014 Coping false
Saw 2 Locker 3 2014 Coping true
Saw 12 Locker 1 2016 Japanese false
Saw 3 Locker 1 2016 Hack true
Saw 5 Locker 4 2016 Hand true
Saw 6 Locker 4 2019 Hand true
Drill 16 Locker 5 2019 false true
Drill 17 Locker 5 2019 false true
Drill 18 Locker 5 2001 true false
Saw 20 Locker 6 2001 Hack false
Saw 21 Locker 6 2001 Hack true
Saw 31 Locker 7 2021 Japanese false
Saw 32 Locker 7 2021 Japanese false
Saw 33 Locker 7 2021 Japanese true
Saw 34 Locker 7 2018 Coping false
```

Comment: Magnificent! Thank you so much for the help and a thoughtful explanation. Really appriciate it! <3

Comment: How would you create a different class with a public method which prints out only the drills which need Bit replacements ?

Comment: @JonathanS. if you have a new question then post it as a separate question. Don't ask new questions in a comment. You now know how to obtain a `List<Equipment>` from your text file. Now you want to know how to extract certain elements from that `List` based on some criteria. I suggest that you first search by entering **[java] filter a list** in the search box at the top of this Web page. If you don't find anything appropriate (which I very much doubt) then post a new question.